# Howto cleanup build environment with maven-invoker-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-invoker-plugin

Sometimes, integration tests running with `maven-invoker-plugin` need some environment preparation.
There is a good way of doing this setup - use `setupIncludes` configuration property to specify set of special integration modules, which will be executed before the others (
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/prepare-build-env.html)

That's nice, but sometimes we also need a teardown procedure, to cleanup the environment after all integration tests are finished (whenever they where passed or not).

Is there any way to perform this kind of teardown activity with `maven-invoker-plugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indicate a [pre/post script](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html) to perform any cleaning or validation tasks for each project in the org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-invoker-plugin:2.0.0:integration-test goal but also you may want to perform any set up or tear down by executing any plugins in the pre-integration-test and post-integration-test lifecycles.

Comment: so, `maven-invoker-plugin` doesn't have the way to specify some special module to run as a cleanup, right?

Comment: Not to clean up, only for setting up you can define which projects should run. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/prepare-build-env.html